# C# 2 root elements Split ADO XML string into 2 files

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

This is first time using C#. Using it because of the ADO xml format i have made a program to receive XML data from serial COM port every 10 mins.

My problem when data is received i get a string from the COM port of 2 XML files i have put a example below when i try and read this file i get an error about multiple root elements

sBuffer has all the XML data and currently writes it out to data.xml
I would like some help to split sBuffer string into 2 parts with each xml to save as

C:\Data\data1.xml

C:\Data\data2.xml

C#

```
 private Task processData(string sBuffer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NEW DATA");           

        string filePath = @"C:\Data\data.xml";
        string text = sBuffer;

        return WriteTextAsync(filePath, text);
    }
```

XML

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"  
  xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"  
  xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">  
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">  
  <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">  
  <s:AttributeType name="ShipperID"/>  
  <s:AttributeType name="CompanyName"/>  
  <s:AttributeType name="Phone"/>  
  <s:Extends type="rs:rowbase"/>  
  </s:ElementType>  
  </s:Schema>  
   <rs:data>  
     ...  
  </rs:data>  
</xml> 
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"  
  xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"  
  xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">  
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">  
  <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">  
  <s:AttributeType name="ShipperID"/>  
  <s:AttributeType name="CompanyName"/>  
  <s:AttributeType name="Phone"/>  
  <s:Extends type="rs:rowbase"/>  
  </s:ElementType>  
  </s:Schema>  
   <rs:data>  
     ...  
  </rs:data>  
</xml>
```

Comment: You should split data as you are receiving the data.  Search in input for the string  : <"/xml">, then write to file and open new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your data by `<wrapper>` tag or use XML reader configurations:

```
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, settings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name.Equals("xml"))
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry this does not help im trying to save this string from serial port as 2 xml files

Comment: So, you can wrap your string with `<wrapper>` then use `xmlDoc.SelectNodes("wrapper\xml");` to have 2 nodes, then save it to 2 files accordingly. Or you can use the above method to be able to read XML string, then you store to a variable for each "xml" before saving to 2 files.